# How to count items' occurence in a List

Tags: list, dart

I am new to Dart.  Currently I have a List of duplicate items, and I would like to count the occurence of them and store it in a Map.

```
var elements = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "f", "g", "h", "h", "h", "e", "a"];
```

I want to have a result like:

```
{
  "a": 3,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 2,
  "d": 2,
  "e": 2,
  "f": 1,
  "g": 1,
  "h": 3
}
```

I did some research and found a JavaScript solution, but I don't know how to translate it to Dart.

```
var counts = {};
your_array.forEach(function(x) { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1; });
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Play around with this:

```
  var elements = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "f", "g", "h", "h", "h", "e"];
  var map = Map();

  elements.forEach((element) {
    if(!map.containsKey(element)) {
      map[element] = 1;
    } else {
      map[element] += 1;
    }
  });

  print(map);
```

What this does is:

- loops through list elements
- if your map does not have list element set as a key, then creates that element with a value of 1
- else, if element already exists, then adds 1 to the existing key value

Or if you like syntactic sugar and one liners try this one:

```
  var elements = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "f", "g", "h", "h", "h", "e"];
  var map = Map();

  elements.forEach((x) => map[x] = !map.containsKey(x) ? (1) : (map[x] + 1));

  print(map);
```

There are many ways to achieve this in all programming languages!

Comment: Thanks for your help !  I would like to know if it was possible to use dart => notation  like in my  JS example.

Comment: Yes you can, I updated the answer with one more example that uses => and short if / else using ? as a syntactic sugar.

Comment: Thank you very much Matija.

Comment: I think more should use the 'update' method on maps. The same code could be written as this which I think are more clean:

`elements.forEach((e) => map.update(e, (x) => x + 1, ifAbsent: () => 1));`

Comment: You can also use: `for (var x in elements) map[x] = (map[x] ?? 0) + 1;` to update the map.

Comment: Lrn: That is also a nice clean example! :)

Comment: Your last example with ?? is great! But honestly, if I was doing this, I would use first example from my answer, its just more readable and easier to understand what you are doing :D

Answer (score 12):

The shorter way to count items' occurrence in a List

List of items. Count items equal 1.

```
List<int> lst = [0,1,1,1,0,8,8,9,1,0];
int res = lst.map((element) => element == 1 ? 1 : 0).reduce((value, element) => value + element);
```

List of objects. Count objects, which property age equals 1.

```
class Person {
   int age;
   
   Person(this.age);
}

List<Person> lst2 = [Person(1), Person(0), Person(1), Person(0)];
int res2 = lst2.map((element) => element.age == 1 ? 1 : 0).reduce((value, element) => value + element);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `fold` with a map:

```dart
final elements = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "f", "g", "h", "h", "h", "e", "a"];

var counts = elements.fold<Map<String, int>>({}, (map, element) {
  map[element] = (map[element] ?? 0) + 1;
  return map;
});

print(counts);
```

Out: `{a: 3, b: 2, c: 2, d: 1, e: 2, f: 1, g: 1, h: 3}`

Answer (score 0):

In the end it all boils down to the FOR loop

```
void main() {
  final elements = [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "f",
    "g",
    "h",
    "h",
    "h",
    "e",
    "a"
  ];

  Map resp = {};
  for (var items in elements) {
    int count = 0;
    for (var val in elements) {
      if (items == val) count++;
      resp[items] = count;
    }
  }
  print(resp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
groupBy(elements, e => e).map((k, v) => MapEntry(k, v.length))
```

The first `groupBy(elements, e => e)` gives you `Map<String, List<String>>`

Then it maps to `Map<String, int>`

Ref: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/groupBy.html