# Is there any way to add FieldValue.increment() inside FieldValue.arrayUnion?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I created a shopping cart app. When user clicks the same product I want to increment number.
if the user clicks the same item 10 times, I want to update firestore like this.

`items:[{'productId':'1234','count':10},{'productId':'1111','count':1}]`

So, I decided to use `FieldValue.increment(1)`. But I got an error when adding it inside `arrayUnion`

**Error**

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Invalid data. FieldValue.increment() can only be used with set() and update(), null)
```

**code**

```
  Future<void> addToCart(ProductModel model){
    var ref = _db.collection('cart').document('7iRLSvH5sgMjaBNw0V4E');

    return ref.setData({
      'userId':'1234',
      'items':FieldValue.arrayUnion([{
        'count':FieldValue.increment(1),
        'productId':model.subCategoryId,
        'productName':model.subCategoryName
      }])
    },merge: true);
  }
```

Comment: Could you share the error message?

Comment: @ralemos I added error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Invalid data. FieldValue.increment() can only be used with set() and update(), null)

As the error clearly states, you can use `FieldValue.increment()` only when using `set()` and `update()` functions and **not** when using `FieldValue.arrayUnion`. You cannot add an element to an array and increment one of its elements at the same time. Besides that, `FieldValue.increment()` can only increment a property of type number which should exist distinct within a document and **not** as a member of an array.

If you need to increment the value of an array member, you should get that array on the client, get the desired element, update it and then write the document back.

**Edit:**

If the following item:

```
[{'productId':'1234','count':10}]
```

It is an object with two properties that exist within an array of objects, you cannot use `FieldValue.increment()`, to increment the `count` property of a single object. You cannot simply map that object into a custom object. Actually, you have in your document a list of HashMaps. So you need to write code for that, by iterating through the list, find the corresponding `count` property you want to increment, increment it and then write the document back.

Comment: What do you mean through "calculate items"? Calculate the sum of numbers in an array?

Comment: if user click same item 10 times, I want to update firestore like this. ```items:[{'productId':'1234','count':10},{'productId':'1111','count':1}]```

Comment: I want to add like this scenario to firestore.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55580075/8822337

Comment: That's not the exact same scenario since there are simply strings in that array and you have objects. So you cannot increment that directly in the database the way you do. The only solution you currently have is the one in my answer. I also encourage you to file a feature [request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact).