# Get most popular value in a list

Tags: flutter, dart

How I can get the most popular number from a list in dart without using any third party libraries?

```
var list = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]; // most popular number is 2
```

If there are two or more popular numbers then the output should be a List with both values. Example:

One popular number:

```
var list = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4];
// Output should be [2]
```

Two or more popular numbers:

```
var list = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3];
// Output should be [2, 3]
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: good point! then it would be great to provide a list of popular numbers. I will edit my question. Thanks!

Comment: create a map and use the number as a key and no of times appear in the list as value. Then get the max from there.

Comment: This one worked for me : [https://stackoverflow.com/a/60732984/12466337](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60732984/12466337) Give it a try :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works...you can optimize it

```
  var list = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  list.sort();
  var popularNumbers = [];
  List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> data = [];
  var maxOccurrence = 0;

  var i = 0;
  while (i < list.length) {
    var number = list[i];
    var occurrence = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
      if (j == i) {
        continue;
      }
      else if (number == list[j]) {
        occurrence++;
      }
    }
    list.removeWhere((it) => it == number);
    data.add({number: occurrence});
    if (maxOccurrence < occurrence) {
      maxOccurrence = occurrence;
    }
  }

  data.forEach((map) {
    if (map[map.keys.toList()[0]] == maxOccurrence) {
      popularNumbers.add(map.keys.toList()[0]);
    }
  });

  print(popularNumbers);
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution fit exactly my expectations. A list with ONLY most popular numbers.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

try this to count each element in list:

```
var list = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4];
  var popular = Map();

  list.forEach((l) {
    if(!popular.containsKey(l)) {
      popular[l] = 1;
    } else {
      popular[l] +=1;
    }
  });
```

Comment: copy pasted from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579906/how-to-count-items-occurence-in-a-list

Comment: Very Innovative just one tip... its a good practise to avoid using 'l'(small L) or 'I'(capital i) as a variable name especially when you are using '1' in the same block. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I guess I found the solution.

**Let me explain it to you:**

I had queried through your list and checked whether the keys of the map contains the element or not. If the map does not contain the element as the key then, it will create a key from the element and pass 1 as the value. If the map does contain the element as a key then it will simply increment the value.

Once the map is ready, I had sorted the map values and stored them in a List. From the sorted map values I had taken the last element from the list of sorted values because we had sorted it in ascending order so the most popular value will be at last.

At last, I had queried through the map and check whether the value of the particular key is equal to the `popularValue` or not. If it is then we are adding the current key and value to the `mostPopularValues` list.

If I got something wrong please let me know.

```
 void main() {
  List list = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4];

  List mostPopularValues = [];

  var map = Map();

  list.forEach((element) {
    if (!map.containsKey(element)) {
      map[element] = 1;
    } else {
      map[element] += 1;
    }
  });

  print(map);
  // o/p : {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1}

  List sortedValues = map.values.toList()..sort();

  print(sortedValues);
  // o/p : [1, 1, 2, 3, 3]

  int popularValue = sortedValues.last;

  print(popularValue);
  // o/p : 3

  map.forEach((k, v) {
    if (v == popularValue) {
      mostPopularValues.add("$k occurs $v time in the list");
    }
  });

  print(mostPopularValues);
  // o/p : [1 occurs 3 time in the list, 2 occurs 3 time in the list]
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i replace the numbers with strings in the lists and this can't seem to work. The error says that a non-null string must be provided.

Comment: @VegetaSaiyan can you please help me with your code ?

Comment: thanks for your reply, i hope you can get another 10 pts so I asked a qtn @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67752313/printing-the-most-frequent-value-in-a-text

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem by defining an extension on `Iterable`:

```
extension MostPopularItemsExtension<E> on Iterable<E> {
  /// Returns the most popular items, where all items in the returned
  /// list have the same number of occurances. If [this] is empty, returns an
  /// empty list
  ///
  /// Examples:
  ///   `[1,2,3,2].mostPopularItems() == [2]`
  ///   `[1,1,2,2].mostPopularItems() == [1,2]`
  Iterable<E> mostPopularItems() {
    if (isEmpty) return [];
    final itemsCounted = <E, int>{};
    for (final e in this) {
      if (itemsCounted.containsKey(e)) {
        itemsCounted[e] = itemsCounted[e]! + 1;
      } else {
        itemsCounted[e] = 1;
      }
    }
    final highestCount = (itemsCounted.values.toList()..sort()).last;
    return itemsCounted.entries
        .where((e) => e.value == highestCount)
        .map((e) => e.key);
  }
}
```

The basic idea is to count all occurrences of each item in a `Map` object, get the highest count from this map and then return all items that have that specific number of occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's the best solution, but it works pretty well. Let me know if there are any doubts.

```dart
    final list = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4];

    // Count occurrences of each item
    final folded = list.fold({}, (acc, curr) {
      acc[curr] = (acc[curr] ?? 0) + 1;
      return acc;
    }) as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;

    // Sort the keys (your values) by its occurrences
    final sortedKeys = folded.keys
        .toList()
        ..sort((a, b) => folded[b].compareTo(folded[a]));

    print('Most popular value: ${sortedKeys.first}'); // 1
    print('Second most popular value: ${sortedKeys[1]}'); // 2
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i replace the numbers with strings in the lists and this can't seem to work. The error says that a non-null string must be provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with something like this, regardless if its strings or integers

```
void main() {
    var userInputs = [1,2,2,2,0,1,0,2,2]; 
    int mostPicked = -1;
    for(var i in userInputs.toSet().toList()) {
      var countOfI = userInputs.where((e)=> i==e).toList().length;
      print('user used $i  $countOfI times');
      if(countOfI > mostPicked){
         mostPicked = i;
      }
    }
    print('most picked: $mostPicked');
}
// Output: 
user used 1  2 times
user used 2  5 times
user used 0  2 times
most picked: 2
```