# Printing the most frequent value in a text

Tags: list, flutter, dart

Let's say I have a list of string.

I saw the code on: [How to count items' occurence in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579906/how-to-count-items-occurence-in-a-list)

I want to print the most frequent string as a text in my widget. How do i run this and print it in there?

Do i go by void main() ?

```
class user with ChangeNotifier {
  static String topWord;

  notifyListeners();
}

void countWord() {
var elements = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "f", "g", "h", "h", "h", "e"];
  var popular = Map();

  elements.forEach((element) {
    if(!popular.containsKey(element)) {
      popular[element] = 1;
    } else {
      popular[element] +=1;
    }
  });

  print(popular);
return user.topWord = popular; 
}
```

Attached are some screenshots when I return the results

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Comment: Make a new function and paste your code in it and end of your function type `return map` now you can use the returned value to print in your widget.

Comment: @ChiragBargoojar have a look at the edited code Chirag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can first create the map of your counted values and then using that map you can get the maximum value of the key.

Source [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60722067/11855654)

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  String email;
  var maxocc = maxOccurance();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("App Bar"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text(maxocc),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

String maxOccurance() {
  var elements = [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "f",
    "g",
    "h",
    "h",
    "h",
    "e"
  ];

  // Here creating map of all values and counting it
  final folded = elements.fold({}, (acc, curr) {
    acc[curr] = (acc[curr] ?? 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  }) as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
  print(folded);

  // Here getting maximum value inside map
  final sortedKeys = folded.keys.toList()
    ..sort((a, b) => folded[b].compareTo(folded[a]));

  return "${sortedKeys.first} occurs maximun times i.e. ${folded[sortedKeys.first]}";
}
```

Output Here

[image: output]