# Return and display the count of items from a list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of Strings:

```
list = ['a','b','b','c','a',d]
```

I want to display the strings in the list in a column with the count next to them. Eg a:2, b:2 etc...

```
Column(
children[
...list.map(letter)=> Text()...

]
)
```

any pointers would be welcome..

Comment: have you considered using a [list view builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html)?

Comment: I'll have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579906/how-to-count-items-occurence-in-a-list) as an example I managed to do the following:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final list = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd'];

  List<Widget> countOccurence(List<String> myList) {
    final myMap = Map();

    myList.forEach(
      (element) {
        if (!myMap.containsKey(element)) {
          myMap[element] = 1;
        } else {
          myMap[element] += 1;
        }
      },
    );

    return myMap.entries.map((entry) => Text('${entry.key}:${entry.value}')).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      ...countOccurence(list),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: I haven't been clear enough. But what I'm looking for is 2:b,2:a, 1:a, 1:d. I need to count the items in the list and display them

Comment: i see, i misread you question, my bad... so, just to be clear, you need to display them by sorting with the amount of repetitions right?

Comment: sorry, got distracted ..I'll have a look now