# Dart: transform a list into a number of occurrences list

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I saw examples on how to do kind of similar stuff but never exactly what I want, I'm wondering how to do it properly so if you can give me an hint I would be really happy ! :)

```
["a","a","b","a","c","c"] =====> [3,1,2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579906/how-to-count-items-occurence-in-a-list) you can do like this:

```
var allStrings = ["a", "a", "b", "a", "c", "c"];
var map = Map();

allStrings.forEach((x) => map[x] = !map.containsKey(x) ? (1) : (map[x] + 1));

print((map.values).toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final list = ["a","a","b","a","c","c"];
Map<String, int> map = {};
for(var i in list){
  if(!map.containsKey(i)){
    map[i] = 1;
 }
  else{
    map[i]=map[i]!+1;
  }
}
print(map.values.toList());
```

Comment: `map[i]++` will unconditionally run because it can be `null`. So to fix that you can write something like this `map[i]=map[i]!+1;`